SSD Cannot be Removed
We have a computer with 2 SSD disks in place. They both have Ubuntu installed, but only one is actually used. The one that is used is the second disk that we have installed Ubuntu on, and that disk is encrypted (decrypted at boot with a password).
We are unable to remove the original disk to put it into a different computer because when we boot, it says to select a disk and boot or something similar to that. This was NOT grub, I think it was something else. We went into the bios and saw that the boot order was still correct: the encrypted disk was supposed to boot. It didn't though.
We put the old disk back in and the grub selector that had Ubuntu, advanced options for Ubuntu, etc. was back, and it could boot perfectly fine.
I thought that maybe it was that grub was only on the old SSD, but I found /etc/default/grub on both filesystems. Maybe the "active" grub is on the old one?
If so, how do I select the new SSD as the one that has the "active" grub?

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Does both the SSDs have an EFI System Partition (ESP) each? Add these information to your question.

Yeah what @user68186 said, please post the output of sudo dd if=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1 | xxd | grep GRUB (replace "X" with your drives' letters, run it twice once for each device) and the output of sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd*

@kos comment only works if old BIOS/MBR install. And I do not suggest dd as any typo can cause major drive erasure. To see all details use Boot-Repair's report: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Thanks @oldfred I was going to suggest boot-repair as well. Here are a bit more detailed steps: Create a Boot-Repair live USB and boot from that USB while the problem SSD is connected and the working SSD is disconnected. Open the app boot-repair. Generate the report and let it upload to pastebin. Make a copy of the pastebin link as you will need it later. Add the pastebin link to your question.

@oldfred Well yep that was the idea, no output = no GRUB = EFI. Otherwise we'd know exactly on which drive GRUB is installed in. But I second being careful while writing those commands down, either write exactly what I wrote or do nothing. Assuming drives are mapped to /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, copy and paste straight into the terminal: sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 | xxd | grep GRUB and sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1 | xxd | grep GRUB. You could avoid typing these down in the event that sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd* reports an EFI partition on one of the drives.
